# In ghost, how to sticky all the featured posts on the top?

Tags: themes, ghost-blog

I want to add the function of sticking the featured posts on the top in the first page. I found this - [Custom Featured Post Styling](https://www.ghostforbeginners.com/custom-featured-post-styling/), but this method can only sticky the posts on the top of that page which the post originally display due to the context limitation.

> The {{#foreach}} helper does not perform queries, and can only operate on the data available to it in the current template scope. You can find out what data a template has access to by looking it up in the context table.

For example, if there are 3 pages and the article `test` is displayed on the page 2, then I mark it as featured and check the first page, however,  `test` won't be displayed on it.

My question is: how to sticky all the featured posts, no matter where they originally display, on the top of my first page?